# How to write test for this trigger

Tags: trigger, unit-test, code-coverage

Want to write Test case and unit test for this trigger

```
    trigger Autoleadconversion on Lead (after insert, after update) {
        for (Lead lead : Trigger.new) {
            if (lead.isConverted == false) //to prevent recursion
            {
                Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
                lc.setLeadId(lead.Id); 
                String oppName = lead.Name;
                lc.setOpportunityName(oppName);
                LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM 
                                            LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];
                lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);
                Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
                System.assert(lcr.isSuccess());            
           }
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you insert/update the lead the trigger will get coverge

Test Class:

```
 @isTest
 public class ConvertLead_Test{
  public static testmethod void testLead(){
  Lead le=new Lead();
   le.Company = 'JohnMiller';
   le.LastName = 'Mike';
   le.Status = 'Open';
     //add all the required fields
    le.isConverted=false;
   insert le;
   //update a field in lead
     le.LastName='John';
    update le;
```

Please check Trailead modules for basic understating for test class:

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_testing/apex_testing_intro

Comment: Thank you Friend

Comment: If it resolves your query.Please make it as a answer

Comment: But New lead is not creating after the test success

Comment: /What do you mean by newLead?

Comment: While i test the code above this page.It should create a lead know?

Comment: whatever the record you created in test class. it will not create in salesforce data base.read more about test class in trailhead you will come to know. mean while check this link:https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000DARWIA4